# Can't get to element in Selenium (Zoom and Scroll not working)

Tags: java, selenium, automation, ui-automation

The website that I am running selenium on has some components that fall off the screen.  I have tried to scroll down to it, zoom out of the page to make it fit and so on.  It is a div modal that contains a button that I need to press.

Here are my previous attempts:

1) Scrolling to the location
The first issue was that whenever I try scrolling, using code or using my own mouse in the window, all that would happen was that the page behind the modal would scroll rather than the modal itself scrolling.  This only happens when running Selenium.  As such, the below code did not work.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0," + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manual-order-modal-ignore-validation\"]")).getLocation().x + ")");
```

It actually scrolls but like I said above, the necessary element never ended up on the screen.

2) Zooming out #1

I tried using Javascript to zoom out of the page which did the job but it apparently threw off my Selenium driver, as it was trying to click on the original location of the button and was not able to find it there.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='80%'");
```

Likewise, I also tried using the below solution but it didn't work either.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.body.style.transform='scale(0.8)'");
```

3) Zooming out #2

I tried sending multiple key strokes but the only thing I got was an error saying "cannot focus element"

```
WebElement html = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.SUBTRACT));
```

4) Zooming out #3

I tried using the robot class but it didn't scroll at all, it just sat there.

```
for (int i=0; i< 6; i++)
{
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
   System.out.println("zoom out")
}
```

The "zoom out" gets printed but no actions are taken.

As you can see, I have looked up and tried many solutions to no avail.  If you have any ideas on how to solve this issue, it would be much appreciated!  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even though I could never scroll down to the button, turns out you can just click it by executing Javascript in selenium.  It's kinda hacky but here's my approach was this:

`((JavascriptExecutor)driver); 
js.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"manual-order-sav‌​e-button\").click()"‌​);`

Doing so allowed me to click on it without it being visible.

*Disclaimer:* I realize that this is not in the spirit of UI-automation because it doesn't quite simulate a user's actions, but if you are stuck in a situation like me where WebDriver acts incorrectly, this hack might work.

Thank you kushal for the input.

Answer (score 1):

We can scroll using Sikuli too.It has 3 functions to scroll, those may help you:

```
screen.wheel(direction, steps);
screen.wheel(target, direction, steps);
screen.wheel(target, direction, steps, stepDelay);
```

Example:

```
import org.sikuli.script.Button; 
button = new Button(); 
screen.wheel(RegionForScroll, button.WHEEL_UP, 5);
```

Comment: Do you know where I can get the maven dependency for it?  Everything that I try off google results in the sikuli part of the import statement being highlighted red.

Comment: Hi hello297, I have downloaded Sikulixsetup-1.1.0.jar from https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download website and click on that jar to setup. After installing that, added sikulixapi.jar as external jar in Buildpath. I didn't try with Maven dependecy, however I have found below dependency in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-core/1.0.0, try this.`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manual-order-modal-ignore-validation\"]"))));

 Actions action = Actions(driver);
 action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"manual-order-modal-ignore-validation\"]"))).build().perform();
```

**UPDATE:**

JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);

js.executeScript("argument[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.id("Your element ID"));

Comment: This doesn't work because the button is never on the screen so all I get is a ElementNotVisibleException.  I first need a way to get the element onto the screen first and then be able to click it.

Comment: Element is present on DOM; so use Explicit wait till that item becomes visible; try my updated answer.

Comment: The issue is that I can't scroll to the element, so no matter how long I wait, it just timesout and errors.  Essentially, the element is loading in the DOM, but off the screen.  I need a way to access it outside of the screen or to get it onto my screen.

Comment: If you just want to click the button you can use JavascriptExecutor to do so; check my updated answer

Comment: Okay I ended up using a similar approach but not exactly yours.  I used 

`JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
js.executeScript("document.getElementById(\"manual-order-save-button\").click()");`

Thanks a bunch kushal!